# xml as3 problem

Tags: actionscript-3

Getting this error when I try to test the xml as3 script:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at xml_images_fla::MainTimeline/processXML()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Can anyone see if the code is so far not working properly or is it somewhere esle?

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Loader;

var columns:Number;

var my_x:Number;
var my_y:Number;
var my_thumb_width:Number;
var my_thumb_height:Number;
var my_images:XMLList;
var my_total:Number;
var container_mc:MovieClip;

var XMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

XMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("gallery.xml"));

XMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);


function processXML(e:Event):void{

    var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    columns = myXML.@COLUMNS;
    my_x = myXML.@XPOSITION;
    my_y = myXML.@YPOSITION;
    my_thumb_width = myXML.@WIDTH;
    my_thumb_height = myXML.@HEIGHT;
    my_images = my_images.length();

    createContainer();
    callThumbs();

}

function createContainer():void{

    container_mc = new MovieClip();
    container_mc.x = my_x;
    container_mc.y = my_y;
    addChild(container_mc);

}

function callThumbs():void{

    for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++){
        var thumb_url = my_images[i].@THUMB;;
        var thumb_loader = new Loader();
        thumb_loader.load(new URLRequest(thumb_url));
        thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);

    }
}


function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void{

    var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
    container_mc.addChild(my_thumb);
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of(if not all of) your xml. Also on a separate note, you should rename your variables from this `my_thumb_width` to this `myThumbWidth` or better yet this `thumbWidth`. Also `XMLLoader` should be `xmlLoader`. Finally it might be better to rename your `processXML()` event handler to `onXmlLoaderComplete()` or `onXMLLoaderComplete()`. Also you might want to consider writing your code in the document class as opposed to the timeline.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_images = my_images.length();
```

That line is probably your issue. `my_images` isn't defined yet at this point.

Comment: Oh thats supposed to be my_total = my_images.length(); but still get the error. I'm guessing its still undefined.

Comment: Yah, my_images doesn't get defined anywhere as far as I can see.

Comment: yes, but you're trying to get the length of my_images. So if my_images is null, you get the error.

Comment: Ok then I'm guessing I missed something out of the tutorial or they missed that part so far before telling me to test.

Comment: I have my_total in the for loop. Does that still mean it's undefined?

Comment: NVM found it. You were right my_images wasn't defined in processXML. Thanks

Comment: Yah, my_images needs to be defined before you can start using it. Can you post your xml (or some of it)?